# Unable to deploy mvc4 application into iis7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I am deploying my mvc4 application into windows server2008 r2(iis7). When i click on browse i am getting below error message

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I went to registry  and tried to change dword to 1 but dword i cannot see. inside fusion folder GACChangenotification and nativeimageindex two folders are there where i can find dword? and is this is the real solution?

this is my stacktrace.

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap.Initialize() +0

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +12619939
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +12619660
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +280
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618980
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458597
```

also it shows below lines of code.

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

it works fine in local system.when i deployed to production server it gives me above error

Comment: This suggest that some dll are missing from your solution, but without a stacktrace there is no way of knowing what is causing this

Comment: It works fine in local. i deployed to other server now its giving problem. i put my stacktrace above.

Comment: can you check that the System.Web.Mvc is among the dll deployed???

Comment: i can see system.web.mvc.dll inside the bin folder